# How to Handle Data vs Visual Representation Granularity Mismatch in Line Chart?

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

A bit simplifying here but I'm facing a problem with granularity when representing data in Time/Value format visually as a [Line Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_chart). Where let's say, the Value is Balance of a bank account.

The minimum granularity permissible for display on Line Chart is by minute. However, data as shown in table below may change multiple times within a minute. For example, in the minute of 9:03 in the table below.

```
Time        Value
-------     -----       
9:01:30     100
9:02:40     200
9:03:10     1000
9:03:20     200
9:03:50     300
9:04:10     400
9:05:20     500
```

What's the best way to represent such data with granularity mismatch?

A couple of approaches I've considered -

1. To show only the last value for a given minute (300 in this case as last recorded value for 9:03). However, this way I will miss the fluctuations that happened within that minute?
2. To use average of all the points within a minute. However, this may be confusing as the user may not be able to match changes in balance with corresponding transactions.

Please suggest any common algorithms / techniques to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: The Time dimension captures Hours, Minutes and Seconds. If you use minutes, you can't look at the value fluctuation by seconds. However, seconds fluctuation may be insignificant, and you may take an average value for minutes. Is seconds significant for what you are trying to look?